# ssh through port 443 alongside webserver

Tags: ssh, webserver, ssl

I'm looking to move ssh off port 22, and had tried out sslh;

[sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml) ssl/ssh multiplexer - accepts HTTPS, SSH, OpenVPN, tinc and XMPP connections on the same port. This makes it possible to connect to any of these servers on port 443 (e.g. from inside a corporate firewall, which almost never block port 443) while still serving HTTPS on that port.

However those services then see traffic originate from 127.0.0.1, instead of the external host making the request - for authentication/logging/identification purposes I've had to disable sslh.

Recommendations for alternative options?

Should I investigate using stunnel to proxy ssh through nginx?

Comment: If you are using a tunnel or proxy then the source IP address will always be the endpoint rather than the origin.  It has be this way for reply packets to get sent to the endpoint rather than the origin.

Comment: yes but with proxying you can add headers, to trace the source ip

Comment: For web services certainly.  What about vpn and ssh and tinc and xmpp?

Comment: I was curious if this was possible on a lower layer than the Application Layer